# Mac upgrade from 10.6 to 10.7

Tags: mac-osx-server

Is upgrading from Mac OS X 10.6 Server to OS X 10.7 Server supported?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is both supported and common assuming you meet the [minimum system requirements for 10.7](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4949).